# How to clear up barchart in ggplot2 in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have created the following barplot using `ggplot2` in RMarkdown. In Markdown's PDF Viewer (once I hit knit), the graph is clear and each bar is separated by small white lines (as seen in the first attached image). However, in my actual PDF file the barchart these small white lines disappear and the bar chart is a lot less legible (2nd attached image). Does anyone know how to fix this so that my actual PDF looks the same as the Markdown PDF viewer?

Here is my code

```
ggplot(data, aes(fill=Key, y=Value, x=Date)) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0,col='red', linetype='dashed', size=1) +
  labs(title = 'Subcomponents of the AFSI', subtitle = '2004Q1 - 2018Q4',
       caption = '*Source = Bank of Namibia', y='Z-Scores') +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#BD215B','#EFBE93','#75002B')) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = seq(head(data$Date, 1), 
                            tail(data$Date, 1),
                            by = '2 years'), date_labels = '%b-%Y') +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=30),plot.subtitle = element_text(size=25),plot.caption = element_text(size = 25),strip.text = element_text(size = 25),axis.title=element_text(size=25), legend.title = element_blank(),legend.text = element_text(size=20),legend.key.size = unit(3,"line"),axis.text=element_text(size=20))
```

and a reproductible of my dataset `data`

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(12478, 12570, 12662, 12753, 
12843, 12935, 13027, 13118, 13208, 13300, 13392, 13483, 13573, 
13665, 13757, 13848, 13939, 14031, 14123, 14214, 14304, 14396, 
14488, 14579, 14669, 14761, 14853, 14944, 15034, 15126, 15218, 
15309, 15400, 15492, 15584, 15675, 15765, 15857, 15949, 16040, 
16130, 16222, 16314, 16405, 16495, 16587, 16679, 16770, 16861, 
16953, 17045, 17136, 17226, 17318, 17410, 17501, 17591, 17683, 
17775, 17866, 12478, 12570, 12662, 12753, 12843, 12935, 13027, 
13118, 13208, 13300, 13392, 13483, 13573, 13665, 13757, 13848, 
13939, 14031, 14123, 14214, 14304, 14396, 14488, 14579, 14669, 
14761, 14853, 14944, 15034, 15126, 15218, 15309, 15400, 15492, 
15584, 15675, 15765, 15857, 15949, 16040, 16130, 16222, 16314, 
16405, 16495, 16587, 16679, 16770, 16861, 16953, 17045, 17136, 
17226, 17318, 17410, 17501, 17591, 17683, 17775, 17866, 12478, 
12570, 12662, 12753, 12843, 12935, 13027, 13118, 13208, 13300, 
13392, 13483, 13573, 13665, 13757, 13848, 13939, 14031, 14123, 
14214, 14304, 14396, 14488, 14579, 14669, 14761, 14853, 14944, 
15034, 15126, 15218, 15309, 15400, 15492, 15584, 15675, 15765, 
15857, 15949, 16040, 16130, 16222, 16314, 16405, 16495, 16587, 
16679, 16770, 16861, 16953, 17045, 17136, 17226, 17318, 17410, 
17501, 17591, 17683, 17775, 17866), class = "Date"), Key = c("FDI", 
"FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", 
"FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", 
"FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", 
"FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", 
"FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", 
"FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", 
"FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FDI", "FVI", "FVI", "FVI", "FVI", 
"FVI", "FVI", "FVI", "FVI", "FVI", "FVI", "FVI", "FVI", "FVI", 
"FVI", "FVI", "FVI", "FVI", "FVI", "FVI", "FVI", "FVI", "FVI", 
"FVI", "FVI", "FVI", "FVI", "FVI", "FVI", "FVI", "FVI", "FVI", 
"FVI", "FVI", "FVI", "FVI", "FVI", "FVI", "FVI", "FVI", "FVI", 
"FVI", "FVI", "FVI", "FVI", "FVI", "FVI", "FVI", "FVI", "FVI", 
"FVI", "FVI", "FVI", "FVI", "FVI", "FVI", "FVI", "FVI", "FVI", 
"FVI", "FVI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI", 
"FSI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI", 
"FSI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI", 
"FSI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI", 
"FSI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI", 
"FSI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI", 
"FSI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI", "FSI"), Value = c(-1.82308383012879, 
-1.89384988339205, -1.31208803714086, -0.405678034547817, -0.842104821786295, 
-0.902291227994929, -0.459744934778869, -0.204304525500542, -0.337524551375062, 
-0.131519838838664, -0.224117109932614, 0.392031043977719, 0.666436139278405, 
0.518895839171921, 0.421142848206683, 0.0355708906009095, -0.797031393590841, 
-0.609839827006934, -0.992148850449602, -0.788502364569124, -1.06451664986604, 
-0.414670607716298, -0.830198128458096, -0.797735667766551, -0.417621776361997, 
-0.500564411263732, -0.39188492203286, -0.126069563972074, 0.0552560427787308, 
0.108860339288122, -0.00629733685078461, 0.323634716131088, -0.144193329936316, 
-0.0190263565366567, 0.105466239824005, 0.0560660658383447, -0.170381367585526, 
0.100817132892937, -0.199480684960526, 0.323076920626312, -0.0851768486880761, 
0.269108317590232, 0.281825451845166, 0.453976257956243, 0.0211673976064813, 
0.433259977608202, 0.0014621995376379, 0.078083348939983, 0.200457478519398, 
0.101714777714826, 0.0925625088658866, 0.498691089848999, 4.61460646932078e-05, 
0.0774906904133837, 0.637654030162235, 1.05389423066225, 1.52057700023886, 
0.681024351971663, 0.448790792995043, 0.563760825208168, -2.15061999514517, 
-2.05881382825742, -1.86359907495103, -1.91935224435619, -2.0425862448643, 
-2.22242934570288, -2.16390678715063, -2.09960876615843, -1.46620710699669, 
-1.19582588618755, -1.26990985173005, -0.930303937729856, -0.858997154122282, 
-0.499167800267267, -0.835817072592501, -1.07246079909505, -1.17217022864878, 
-0.822971498955485, -0.973036577752532, -0.430965952774891, -0.815813796308401, 
-1.39844791574032, -1.23785190010313, -1.21551641647221, -1.64774744693728, 
-1.83504396975394, -1.89567418229645, -2.12865411972038, -2.42678233078852, 
-2.25554420045072, -1.74859987890665, -1.73638175225156, -1.49919903483143, 
-1.29891077341251, -1.49097165578767, -1.12894789290261, -1.5354318933698, 
-1.59630672394536, -2.1627214140958, -1.69417596674313, -1.92007198447969, 
-1.78128568193586, -2.04734496354334, -2.10610679566385, -2.41134097249095, 
-2.54322013498187, -2.77145466580415, -2.46976142268522, -1.86653325142151, 
-2.28760603916278, -2.19962071325963, -2.5256533417372, -4.21414005455993, 
-4.29570891139697, -2.81074900066857, -4.5195857585309, -3.15631252725373, 
-2.38605300762868, -3.45309215951776, -3.25455935785649, -0.868692436259391, 
-0.445867001611126, 0.0416820706873672, -0.2459228596273, -1.19093369198886, 
0.297369780855301, -0.175630485466657, -0.202806611413611, -0.443891754081726, 
-0.307410248817137, -0.960011330626974, -1.55875762035777, -0.417526268520341, 
-0.560016360757835, -0.545246042058458, -0.177028085520169, -0.417486350707313, 
-0.530919140367045, -0.407630865360979, -0.0027723216839252, 
-0.348447818751858, 0.0783703293458976, -0.263781322899579, -0.712270850724363, 
-0.535930472155901, -0.253955150615707, -0.0204023578865018, 
0.273467313873591, -0.0744558050736246, -0.0460330891495498, 
0.257191731882834, 0.368777568449419, 0.460806836804316, 0.129335363374439, 
0.125927786254233, 0.281809549052954, 0.0686844633792984, 0.379646583287291, 
0.239553498316811, 0.743456752949791, 0.455132692063603, 1.72068268505694, 
0.644123142019435, 0.538768641488654, 0.432960570651033, 0.564381819930766, 
0.407826976704764, 0.31516791494264, 0.335321742396194, 0.317190806570282, 
0.212742524692262, 0.883882204843472, -0.0273650916562812, -0.245115251706337, 
-0.0209130280489029, 0.216284959835395, 0.76519007757211, 0.611841481447244, 
0.431364484764139, 0.291328467714409)), row.names = c(NA, -180L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: you could add a colour option to the bars, then they will have a coloured line around the outside? But most liekly this is related to the dimensions of the pdf document, if you make it bigger you will probably see more definition